# How to copy images from multiple directories into corresponding multiple destination directories and resize them?

Tags: python, loops, image-processing

How to copy all the images present in multiple sub-directories to another sub-directories corresponding for them using Python? I have the dataset home-folder containing N sub-folders, inside each sub folder a set of images. I want to apply processing on each image in sub-directories and move it into corresponding sub-directory, that is like creating a new dataset image form. A tree like below:

```
+Home-dir
----- +sub-dir1  --->img1,img2,img3,------imgN
----- +sub-dir2  --->img1,img2,img3,------imgN
----- +sub-dir3  --->img1,img2,img3,------imgN
..
----- +sub-dirN  --->img1,img2,img3,------imgN
```

I want to get the following:

```
+Home-dir-process
----- +sub-dir-new1  --->img-new1,img-new2,img-new3,------img-newN
----- +sub-dir-new2  --->img-new1,img-new2,img-new3,------img-newN
----- +sub-dir-new3  --->img-new1,img-new2,img-new3,------img-newN
..
----- +sub-dir-newN  --->img-new1,img-new2,img-new3,------img-newN
```

I'm able to copy all image in one directory into corresponding one directory as following:

```
path1='path\to\before\processing\image'
path2='path\to\save\after\processing\image'
listing = os.listdir(path1)
for file in listing:
    im = Image.open(path1 + '\\' + file)
    img = im.resize((img_rows, img_cols))
    img.save(path2 + '\\' + file, "JPEG")
```

But I want to copy all images in multiple sub-directories into another sub-directories, can anyone please help me?

Comment: @martineau thank you for your reply. yeah I know that it must be loop inside loop, but i cannot able to do that, all my trails was failed. can you please help me with code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I revised my original answer because it really didn't do what you wanted, it basically only did what the code in your questions does—process all the image files in a single folder.

The driver function is named `process_tree()` and its job is to traverse the home directory's sub-directories looking for files in them that match any in a set of the user-specified filename patterns, and if any are found, to create the destination sub-directory, and then call a user-supplied function on each one of them, passing it the existing source file name and the desired output file name, along with any arguments the users wants also passed to the supplied function.

In this code below the sample user-specified function is named `resize_image()`. As the name implies, it only processes one image file.

Note that the processed images have the same name as the source images (i.e. no `-_new` suffix gets added to their filenames).

```
import fnmatch
import os
from PIL import Image

verbose = True  # Global printing flag for vprint().


def process_tree(src, dst, patterns, processing_func, *args):
    vprint(' src: "{src}"'.format(src=src))
    vprint('dst: "{dst}"'.format(dst=dst))
    vprint()
    for dirpath, subdirs, filenames in os.walk(src, topdown=False):
        vprint('PROCESSING dirpath: "{}"'.format(dirpath))
        if dirpath == src:  # Root src directory?
            if not os.path.exists(dst):
                vprint('CREATING dst root: "{dst}"'.format(dst=dst))
                os.makedirs(dst)  # Make root dest folder.
            vprint()
            continue  # Don't process files in root folder.

        # Determine sub-directory of src being processed.
        src_subdir = os.path.relpath(dirpath, src)
        dst_subdir = os.path.join(dst, src_subdir)

        # Determine which files in dirpath match one or more of the patterns.
        if isinstance(patterns, str):
            patterns = (patterns,)  # Convert to single element sequence.
        processible = set(filename for pattern in patterns
                                    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, pattern))
        if not processible:
            vprint('no files to process')  # Output directory not created.
        else:
            if os.path.isdir(dst_subdir):
                vprint('PROCESSING directory "{}"'.format(dst_subdir))
            elif os.path.exists(dst_subdir):
                raise NotADirectoryError('Non-drectory "{}" exists"'.format(dst_subdir))
            else:
                vprint('CREATING directory "{}"'.format(dst_subdir))
                os.makedirs(dst_subdir)

            vprint('processing files:')
            for filename in filenames:
                if filename in processible:
                    src_file_path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                    dst_file_path = os.path.join(dst_subdir, filename)
                    try:
                        processing_func(src_file_path, dst_file_path, *args)
                    except Exception as exc:
                        vprint('  EXCEPTION processing file:\n    {!s}'.format(exc))
                        vprint()
            vprint()


def resize_image(src, dst, scale_factor):
    """ Resize image src by scale_factor and save result to dst. """
    vprint('resizing image:\n'
           '  src: "{src}"\n'
           '  scale factor: {scale_factor}'.format(**locals()))
    img = Image.open(src)
    # Calcuate new size.
    new_width = round(img.width * scale_factor)
    new_height = round(img.height * scale_factor)
    if new_width < 1 or new_height < 1:
        vprint('  width and/or height of scaled version of image "{filename}"\n'
               '  is less than 1 pixel - skipped'.format(filename=os.path.basename(src)))
        return
    resampling_method = Image.BICUBIC
    img = img.resize((new_width, new_height), resample=resampling_method)
    img.save(dst)
    vprint('  resized image saved to "{}"'.format(dst))

def vprint(*args, **kwargs):
    """ Only prints if global flag is set. """
    if verbose:
        return print(*args, **kwargs)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    inputpath  = r'\my\path\to\_source_images'
    outputpath = r'\my\path\to\_processed_images'

    process_tree(inputpath, outputpath, ('*.jpg',), resize_image, .5)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, best wishes.

Comment: @hhtt: Just now realized that this doesn't really answer your question — so am going to delete it.

Comment: @hh tt: See updated answer which I think now does address your question.

Comment: @hh tt: Does this not do what you wanted?

Comment: thank you very much for your interest and sorry to my late response, yeah this is what i want and 'm also solved it in the similar way with os.makedirs nearly time ago, thanks alot with regard.